# React js document event "readystatechange" not called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I recently changed my pc I was working with, uploaded all my code on github and cloned it back and something strange is happening, the readystatechange event of the document is not getting fired anymore.

I use React as my framework and I have this code that wait for the document to be ready to find the dimension in pixels of a flexbox div.

```
function useElementDimension(elementId: string) {
  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({
      height: 0,
      width: 0
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    function onLoaded() {
      if(document.readyState != "complete") return;
      const stage = document.getElementById(elementId);
      if(stage === null) return;
      setDimensions({width: stage.clientWidth, height: stage.clientHeight});
    }

    document.addEventListener('readystatechange', onLoaded);
    return (() => document.removeEventListener('readystatechange', onLoaded));
  });

  return dimensions;
}
```

It was working just fine in my other laptop, the effect is getting called and registering the event but the function onLoaded is never called.
Any idea?

Comment: Which browsers are you using for both of your laptops

Comment: @VinXi chrome in both, I tried also edge and it's the same

Comment: React.useEffect(() => {
    function test() {
      console.log("a");
    }

    document.addEventListener("load", test);
    return (() => document.removeEventListener("load", test));
  });  

I noticed that a couple of events dont fire aswell, the one related to loading, the keydown and others are working..